# Сессии и DAO классы в Hibernate

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, orm

Здравствуйте.

Есть маленький проектик работающий с БД. В качестве ORM решения выбран Hibernate 4.

Попутно обуздывая фреймворк, создал классы сущностей, связал аннотациями, использовал DAO pattern. Но: в имплементации ДАО классов в каждом изменяющем БД методе сессия открывалась и закрывалась прямо в методе (как и в этой туториал ссылочке http://javaxblog.ru/article/java-hibernate-1/). Пример

```
Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            // Здесь добавляю, обновляю или удаляю
            // ...
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Обрабатываю
            // rollback()
        } finally {
            // Закрываю
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
```

Но что-то подсказывает, что это как-то, мягко говоря, не правильно. 
Порыв немного интернет, наткнулся на статейку (https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects), где говорится, что ДАО имплементации не должны создавать сессию внутри, а на неё нужно лишь ссылаться. Если я правильно понял, ДАО имплементаций не должно волновать создание сессий.

> You could also use constructor injection. How you set the Session and what scope this Session has is of no concern to the actual DAO implementation. A DAO should not control transactions or the Session scope.

Интересует вопрос опытных разработчиков: 
создавать ли сессию один раз на всё приложение и просто в сеттере давать ссылочку ДАО классам (при этом сессию не закрывать), или же в каждом методе ДАО класса создавать и закрывать сессию?

Comment: И да, может быть для доступа к сессии использовать синглтон?

Comment: Синглтон не следует использовать вообще нигде, это антипаттерн.

Comment: @pandal если операций слишком много. то вынести за пределы beginTransaction и commit. если мало, то можно и внутри заюзать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование ссылки на SessionFactory внутри реализации DAO и создание сессии на каждый вызов дао методов. Для массивных изменений рекомендуется batch update.

Answer (score 6):

Жаль, что автор не нашёл время сам ответить на свой вопрос. 
Хоть я ни разу не опытный разработчик, попробую ответить на основании информации, которую нашёл в сети на текущий день.
На многих ресурсах рекомендуют использовать Hibernate в связке со Spring. Мне не нравится этот совет тем, что вводится лишняя "сущность". Человек учится пользоваться отвёрткой, а ему хотят всучить шуруповёрт. Да, вроде бы шуруповёрт круче, но и отвёрткой уметь пользоваться тоже не будет лишним.

**Ручное открытие/закрытие сессии.**
В первую очередь напрашивается такая структура взаимодействия: слой DAO содержит только основные (CRUD - create, read, update, delete) операции взаимодействия с базой данных; в бизнес-слой выносятся операции, которые можно (и нужно) объединять в транзакции.
Выглядит DAO-класс примерно так:

```
public class ItemDAOImpl implements ItemDAO {

    private Session session;

    public ItemDAOImpl(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public Item get(long id) {
        return session.get(Item.class, id, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
    }

    @Override
    public long create(Item item) {
        return (Long) session.save(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Item item) {
        session.update(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Item delete(long id) {
        Item item = session.byId(Item.class).load(id);
        session.delete(item);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Сессия `session` создаётся в бизнес-слое и передаётся в конструктор DAO:

```
public class AdminServiceImpl extends PersonServiceImpl implements AdminService {   

    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public AdminServiceImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public long createItem(Item item) throws DBException {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()){
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            ItemDAO dao = new ItemDAOImpl(session);
            long id = dao.create(item);

            transaction.commit();

            return id;
        } catch (HibernateException | NoResultException e) {
            throw new DBException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Item item) throws DBException {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()){
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            ItemDAO dao = new ItemDAOImpl(session);
            dao.update(item);

            transaction.commit();

        } catch (HibernateException | NoResultException e) {
            throw new DBException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteItem(long id) throws DBException {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()){
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            ItemDAO dao = new ItemDAOImpl(session);
            Item item = dao.delete(id);

            transaction.commit();

        } catch (HibernateException | NoResultException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new DBException(e);
        }
    }           
}
```

Недостаток метода очевиден - при большой нагрузке должен активно работать сборщик мусора, чтобы освобождать память от DAO- и сервисных объектов. Это осталось за кадром, но подразумевается, что также должен создаваться объект сервисного класса `AdminServiceImpl`. В конструкторе этот объект получает ссылку на объект типа `SessionFactory`.

**Стратегия открытия сессии**
Чтобы избавиться от постоянного создания dao - и сервисных объектов, нужен механизм создания сессии или получения текущей сессии в каждом из этих объектов независимо друг от друга. И тут на помощь приходят стратегии открытия-закрытия сессии. Рекомендую эту [статью](http://javaoutsource.blogspot.ru/2011/03/hibernate-opensession-getcurrentsession.html) к прочтению.
Допустим, что выбираем стратегию `ManagedSessionContext` - каждому потоку по отдельной сессии. Тогда для получения сессии можно будет использовать
`Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();`

Увы, сразу это не заработает. Чтобы заработало, нужно в `hibernate.cfg.xml` прописать
`<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>`.
Или второй способ - в конфигурацию `hibernate` добавить свойство
`configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");`

Уже знакомый DAO-класс будет теперь выглядеть так:

```
public class ItemDAOImpl implements ItemDAO {

    ItemDAOImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public Item get(long id) {
        return DBService.getSessionFactory()
                .getCurrentSession()
                .get(Item.class, id, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
    }

    @Override
    public long create(Item item) {
        return (Long) DBService.getSessionFactory()
                .getCurrentSession()
                .save(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Item item) {
        DBService.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                .update(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Item delete(long id) {
        Session session = DBService.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Item item = session.byId(Item.class).load(id);
        session.delete(item);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Здесь `DBService` - абстрактный класс, содержащий ссылку на объект `SessionFactory`. Так выглядит функция `getSessionFactory()`:

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

А вот и переделанный сервисный класс:

```
public class AdminServiceImpl extends PersonServiceImpl implements AdminService {

    AdminServiceImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public long createItem(Item item) throws DBException {
        Transaction transaction = DBService.getTransaction();
        try {
            ItemDAO dao = DaoFactory.getItemDAO();
            long id = dao.create(item);

            transaction.commit();

            return id;
        } catch (HibernateException | NoResultException e) {
            DBService.transactionRollback(transaction);
            throw new DBException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Item item) throws DBException {
        Transaction transaction = DBService.getTransaction();
        try {
            ItemDAO dao = DaoFactory.getItemDAO();
            dao.update(item);

            transaction.commit();

        } catch (HibernateException | NoResultException e) {
            DBService.transactionRollback(transaction);
            throw new DBException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteItem(long id) throws DBException {
        Transaction transaction = DBService.getTransaction();
        try {
            ItemDAO dao = DaoFactory.getItemDAO();
            Item item = dao.delete(id);

            transaction.commit();

        } catch (HibernateException | NoResultException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException e) {
            DBService.transactionRollback(transaction);
            throw new DBException(e);
        }
    }            
}
```

Вот используемые функции из DBService:

```
public static Transaction getTransaction(){
        Session session = DBService.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = DBService.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction();
        if (!transaction.isActive()) {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        }
        return transaction;
    }

    public static void transactionRollback(Transaction transaction){
        if (transaction.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ACTIVE
                || transaction.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.MARKED_ROLLBACK) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
    }
```

А вот класс `DaoFactory` для получения инстанса `ItemDAO`:

```
public abstract class DaoFactory {
    private static ItemDAO itemDAO = new ItemDAOImpl();       

    public static ItemDAO getItemDAO() {            
        return itemDAO;
    }           
}
```

Собственно, на этом, думаю, всё.
Для тех, кто хочет пощупать код, вот ссылки на github:
- [ручное управление сессией](https://github.com/golubtsoff/webstore/tree/d5b3799bdf7154b86aa418e3ca8d29c3c857c82d);
- [управление при помощи `ManagedSessionContext`](https://github.com/golubtsoff/webstore).

Comment: Спустя 3 года увидел активность в треде. Получив некоторый опыт за это время, решение проблемы - инжектить SessionFactory. Кстати, по поводу DaoFactory: нету смысла делать static и volatile ссылку, так как уже к инициализации static переменной действует правило Happens Before. Спасибо за развернутый ответ

Answer (score 1):

когда слишком много операций на вставку или обновление необходимо делать, то кадрый раз открытие и закрытие сесии отнимет много времени в совокупности. По этой причине данные действия можно позволить решить выше.

```
private Session currentSession;

private Transaction currentTransaction;

public Session openCurrentSession() {
    currentSession = HibernateUtil.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    return currentSession;
}

public Session openCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
    currentSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
    return currentSession;
}

public void closeCurrentSession() {
    currentSession.close();
}

public void closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
    currentTransaction.commit();
    currentSession.close();
}

public void update(Object o) {
    this.currentSession.update(o);
}
```

таким образом, Вы сами решаете, когда открывать сессию и когда закрывать.

Comment: Думаю, будет ошибкой в dao-классах использовать транзакции. Они должны быть в бизнес-слое, а не в дао.

Comment: согласен, но тут немного другое спрашивают, насколько я понял